# Use standard Debian minimal image for vagrant

Tags: vagrant

I don't want to use a vagrant image hosted on https://vagrantcloud.com/ created once and never change
but rather just use the standard install image provided by Debian.

Is it possible to download it from trusted Debian servers on each vagrant creation?

Answer (score 0):

Vagrant doesn't create VMs from ISO files. You need to have a `.box` file with virtual disk image which is already pre-installed with the OS.

So unless Debian provides their own official Vagrant image files (like Ubuntu), your only choice is to create your own box.